# How to fix frontend javascript in handlebars catching undefined value from server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express-handlebars

I have a JSON object in backend which I want to send to frontend javascript. But I'm constantly encountering "undefined" when trying to access that variable.

candidates is json object and is working fine in server side.

Here's my server side code.

```
res.render('electionview',{title: 'Election', poll: poll, data: JSON.stringify(candidates) });
```

Here's my script in Handlebars

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var candidates = {{{data}}};
console.log(candidates);
<script>
```

But I'm getting this error in console.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'

When I remove semicolon, output in the console is **undefined**. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting candidates as:

```
Candidate.find({}).lean()
       .then(candidates=>res.render("electionview", JSON.stringify(candidates))
```

Removing .lean() fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Server-side:

```
let obj = {};
obj.title = 'Election';
obj.poll = poll;
obj.data = candidates;
res.render('electionview', obj);
```

I'm assuming that the render function already knows how to serve objects as JSON, so no need to `JSON.stringify` anything.

Then, on the client-side, `JSON.parse()` the object above in whole. After that, it should have a `data` property that you can use as needed.

Comment: @Heisenberg : Ok, I updated my answer to be like I'd do it on the server-side. Maybe this will help.